# Creating an account and logging-in using constructor

Tags: java, class, authentication, constructor

User will create an account and the user will login.
User can create multiple accounts.
Inputting wrong login outputs error in pincode or username.
My problem is whenever I create an account and log-in, it does not read what i've inputted in the create account and keep forcing the user to input a valid username and pincode in login.

```
static JavaBank user = new JavaBank();
int accountNumber = 1000;
int initialDeposit;
String name;
private String username;
int pincode;
int verify;

public JavaBank(){
    accountNumber = 1000;
    name = "name";
    username = "username";
    pincode = 1000;
    verify = 1000;
    initialDeposit = 5000;
}

public JavaBank(int accountNumber, String username, String name, int pincode, int verify, int initialDeposit){
    this.username = username;
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.name = name;
    this.pincode = pincode;
    this.verify = verify;
    this.initialDeposit = initialDeposit;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    while(true){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String tempUsername;
    int tempPass;
    int counter = 0;
    int option;
    int valid1 = 1;
    int valid;
    int login = 0;
    JavaBank newUser[] = new JavaBank[10];

    System.out.println("\nJAVA BANK\n");
    System.out.println("[1] Create Account");
    System.out.println("[2] Login Account");
    System.out.println("[3] Exit\n");
    System.out.print("Option: ");
    option = input.nextInt();

    switch(option){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("\n[1] Create Account\n");
            System.out.println("Account Number: "+user.accountNumber);
            System.out.print("Account Name: ");
            user.name = input.next();
            System.out.print("Username: ");
            user.username = input.next();
            do{
            valid = 0;
            System.out.print("Pincode: ");
            user.pincode = input.nextInt();
            if(user.pincode < 1000 || user.pincode > 9999){
                valid = 1;
                System.out.println("Pincode should be 4 digit! Please try again!");
                continue;
            }
            System.out.print("Verify Pincode: ");
            user.verify = input.nextInt();
            if(user.verify < 1000 || user.verify > 9999){
                valid = 1;
                System.out.println("Pincode should be 4 digit! Please try again!");
                continue;
            }
            if(user.pincode != user.verify){
                valid = 1;
                System.out.println("Pincode does not match! Please try again!");
            }
            }while(valid!=0);
            do{
            valid = 0;
            System.out.print("Initial Deposit[Min. of 5000]: ");
            user.initialDeposit = input.nextInt();
            if(user.initialDeposit <5000){
                valid = 1;
                System.out.println("You entered less than 5000! Please try again!");
            } 
            System.out.println("\nCongratulations!");
            System.out.println("Your account has been created succesfully!");
            }while(valid!=0);
            newUser[counter] = new JavaBank(user.accountNumber++, user.username, user.name, user.pincode, user.verify, user.initialDeposit);
            counter++;
            break;
        case 2: 
            do{
            System.out.print("Username: ");
            tempUsername = input.next();
            System.out.print("Pincode: ");
            tempPass = input.nextInt();
            for(int index=0; index<counter; index++){
                if(tempUsername.equals(newUser[index].username)){
                    if(tempPass == newUser[index].pincode)
                        {
                            valid1 = 0;
                            login = index;
                        }
                }
            }
            if(valid1!=0){
                System.out.println("Username or password does not exist. Please try again!");
            }
            }while(valid1!=0);
```

Comment: Your counter variable should be an instance variable and not to be defined inside main(). Please try that and let me know.

Comment: I tried it and worked. would post answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move both the `user[]` and the `counter` from `main()` as static variables.

```
public class JavaBank {
    static JavaBank user = new JavaBank();
    int accountNumber = 1000;
    int initialDeposit;
    String name;
    private String username;
    int pincode;
    int verify;
    private static int counter = 0;//Add here and remove from main()
    private static JavaBank newUser[] = new JavaBank[10];//add here and remove from main()

    public JavaBank() {
        accountNumber = 1000;
        name = "name";
        username = "username";
        pincode = 1000;
        verify = 1000;
        initialDeposit = 5000;
    }
.
.
.
```

What happens is this. You increment the counter and when you enter option again, the counter value and the users are lost. When you make them as `static`, it's available till the program exists.

Comment: Sure. Have a good read about static and instance variables for more knowledge. :)